# Xdebug, cannot accept external xdebug connection. Local value overwriting master

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I've been trying to set up xdebug for PHP CLI commands. I already have it working just fine for debugging Apache 2 (browser/API connections). The server is setup through Vagrant. So I copied over some xdebug settings to my `cli/php.ini`

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

And I setup a bunch of addresses in my IDE (PhpStorm)

[image]

Now when I attempt to use it most of the time nothing happens, but the first time I tried it yesterday and first thing this morning it gave me the message

> Cannot accept external Xdebug connection: Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'.

I also tried adding a `phpinfo()` call to my code and then calling it from the terminal piping it to `grep xdebug`. This gave me the following which shows the local value => master value. I'm concerned by the `xdebug.remote_host` value which appears to have an overwritten local value of 'localhost' but I have no idea how this is happening.

```
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => 10.0.2.2
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: *"I'm concerned by the xdebug.remote_host value which appears to have an overwritten local value"* Do not worry about that: you have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = On` so remote_host value is simply ignored... Just in case: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Thanks for the information

Comment: @LazyOne that link lead me to find XDEBUG_CONFIG which solved my problem. Turns out I had accidentally changed it at some point yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix was as simple as running `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=10.0.2.2"` for me, this sorted out the incorrect local value I had for remote_host